Custom Scrollbar iFrame - React
I would like to use a custom scrollbar on an iframe (integration of another web page in my web page) that includes the general conditions of use.
By doing my research on the internet I understood that we could not modify the scrollbar of an iframe (just like the content of this iframe). If this is true is there another way to get around this? For example hide the default bar and put a parent container the size of the iframe with the custom scrollbar?
You should know that I can potentially access the server where the iframe page is hosted but without changing the content. I can't directly change the scrollbar on the iframe webpage because it is used elsewhere but if you have any ideas on how to work around the problem? Thanks
I tried to add my custom scrollbar class in my iframe but it does not work (the class works on other elements than the iframe).
I use React and Tailwindcss.
const AcceptCgu = () => {
  const [isAccepted, setIsAccepted] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setIsAccepted((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <AuthTemplate>
      <div className="w-[541px] bg-white border border-border-cream rounded-[16px] p-6 flex flex-col gap-4">
        
        <AuthBackButton />
        <AuthTitle>General conditions of use</AuthTitle>

        <div className="h-[292px]">
          <iframe 
            src="https://www.linktomygeneralconditionsofuse"
            className="w-full h-full overflow-y-auto custom-scrollbar"
            title="Conditions Générales d'Utilisation"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="flex justify-center mt-4">
          <SwitchButton isChecked={isAccepted} onToggle={handleToggle} label="I accept the general conditions of use"/>
        </div>

        <AuthSubmitButton disabled={!isAccepted} disabledStyle={!isAccepted} center>
          Continue
        </AuthSubmitButton>
      </div>
    </AuthTemplate>
  );
};

export default AcceptCgu;

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: var(--scrollbar);
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    width: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: var(--main-green);
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: var(--scrollbar);
    border-radius: 7px;
}

